# flat_map dropped here while still borrowed

Tags: dictionary, rust, flat

I'm trying to write a vector with the index of the string and each character in the string.

In the example below, 0 J, 0 a, 0 n ... 1 J, 1i, ...

```
fn main() {
    let names = vec!["Jane", "Jill", "Jack", "Johne"];
    let name3 = names.iter().enumerate().flat_map(|(i, name)| {
        let letters = name.chars();
        let mut is = Vec::new();
        for _k in 0..name.len() {
            is.push(i);
        }
        is.iter().zip(letters).collect::<Vec<_>>()
    });
    for i in name3 {
        println!("{:?}", i);
    }
}
```

This gives me the error

```
error[E0597]: `is` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:9:9
   |
9  |         is.iter().zip(letters).collect::<Vec<_>>()
   |         ^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
10 |     });
   |     - `is` dropped here while still borrowed
...
14 | }
   | - borrowed value needs to live until here
```

I don't understand what is going on here. I've already collected the `is` value.

Weirdly enough, if I flip `letters` and `is`, it works.

```
letters.zip(is)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Calling `is.iter()` returns references to the values inside `is`. Your final iterator type is attempting to return these references, except that the `Vec` holding the values has already been deallocated.

The simplest fix is to switch to `into_iter`, which takes ownership of the `Vec` and all its values. The more efficient fix is to avoid creating a `Vec` at all:

```
fn main() {
    let names = vec!["Jane", "Jill", "Jack", "Johne"];

    let name3 = names
        .iter()
        .enumerate()
        .flat_map(|(i, name)| name.chars().map(move |c| (i, c)));

    for i in name3 {
        println!("{:?}", i);
    }
}
```

> if I flip `letters` and `is`, it works.

Yes, [`zip`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.zip) takes values that implement [`IntoIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html). By flipping the arguments, you end up implicitly calling `into_iter` on the `Vec`. You'd get the same undesired behavior if you did `letters.zip(&is)`.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know about into_iter. This article is helpful for that. http://hermanradtke.com/2015/06/22/effectively-using-iterators-in-rust.html

Comment: Your solution with move c is also really elegant. Thank you.